# Display a splash page instead of splash screen in windows 10 mobile application

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I'am still new to windows 10 application development. I want to show custom xaml page to the user instead of splash screen which only having a logo. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show custom xaml page to the user instead of splash screen which only having a logo.

You could create an extended splash screen for your app. Please read [Display a splash screen for more time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen) document for more details.

Here's an official [Splash screen sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen) for your reference.